# How to access class attributes of a derived class in the base class in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-attributes

I want to do something in a base class (`FooBase`) with the **class attribues** of the derived classes (`Foo`). I want to do this with Python**3**.

```
class BaseFoo:
   #felder = [] doesn't work

   def test():
      print(__class__.felder)

class Foo(BaseFoo):
   felder = ['eins', 'zwei', 'yep']


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    Foo.test()
```

Maybe there is a different approach to this?

Comment: Something's very wrong here. Is `test` supposed to be a *class method* or an *instance method*? It must at the very least accept either `cls` or `self` as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `test` a [class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), and give it an argument that it can use to access the class; conventionally this arg is named `cls`.

```
class BaseFoo:
    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        print(cls.felder)

class Foo(BaseFoo):
    felder = ['eins', 'zwei', 'yep']


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    Foo.test()
```

**output**

```
['eins', 'zwei', 'yep']
```